# Vector space complement to a multiplicatively closed subspace is an ideal

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ of any dimension and suppose we have an associative multiplication $V \times V \to V$ making $V$ into a commutative ring with unity. Let $V=U \oplus W$ be a decomposition of $V$ into complementary subspaces, and suppose further that $U$ is a subring of $V$. Does it follow that $W$ is an ideal of $V$ as a ring?

Comment: Try $V = \mathbb{C}^2$ equipped with the coordinate-wise multiplication and $U = \left<(1,1)\right>$, $W = \left<(2,1)\right>$.

Comment: @EthanAlwaise Do the brackets here correspond to the $\mathbb{C}$-linear span of the respective vectors?

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant, should've been more clear, sorry.